# No extension method 'First' on derived class

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

Given the (very simplied) code.

```
public class Class1 
{
}

public class Class2 : Class1
{
}

public class List1 : System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Class1>
{
    public new System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<Class1> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return new Class1();            
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}


public class List2  : List1 , System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Class2> 
{       
    public new System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<Class2> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return new Class2();              
    }  

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Then the code

```
var l = new List2();
var first = l.First();
```

will not compile, but gives the error

> 'List2' does not contain a definition for 'First' and no extension method 'First' accepting a first argument of type 'List2' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

If List2 is not derived from List1 then it compiles ok, which proves that List2 does have a valid extension method.

Is this simply a case of an misleading error and the problem is it has two many extension methods and doesn't know which one to pick?

If so, why can't it tell that Class2 is more specific version in the same way as the compiler uses with method overload resolution?

Comment: You of course have `using System.Linq;`, right?

Comment: Yes. (Otherwise it won't compile when List2 isn't derived from List1).

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that `List2` implements both `IEnumerable<Class1>` and `IEnumerable<Class2>`, so the compiler doesn't know which of `Enumerable.First<Class1>` or `Enumerable.First<Class2>` to call. Effectively, there is no best `T` that the compiler can find to invoke `Enumerable.First<T>(l)`, and so it does not count any generic `Enumerable.First<T>` as an eligible method. Therefore, it's now looking only for a non-generic method named `First` with a single parameter that `l` can be implicitly converted to, and it can't find any.

You can be explicit and say

```
var first = l.First<Class1>();
```

or

```
var first = l.First<Class2>();
```

and then you're okay.

Comment: What is the difference between these two calls and what do you expect the first.GetType() to return in both cases?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this class :

```
public class List1 : IEnumerable<string>, IEnumerable<object>
        {
            IEnumerator<object> IEnumerable<object>.GetEnumerator()
            {
                return GetEnumerator();
            }

            public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
            {
                return GetEnumerator();
            }
        }
```

so compiler does not know First() method of which of `IEnumerable<string>` or `IEnumerable<object>` to call. this example is simplified version of your situation.

Consider you have written an extension method on a class that you don't have its source code, but then in next version they implement exactly the same method on that class. In this situation your old codes are not reliable anymore, so the best solution is a compile time error.

Answer (score -1):

## What is the problem with Generic methods?

When your class inherit from `List1` and from `IEnumerable<Class2>` it's actually inherits from 3 types: `List1`, `IEnumerable<Class1>` and `IEnumerable<Class2>` (and `object`). That means your class have 2 different implementations for `First<>()` because of that the compiler wont generate the "default" method that takes no generic arguments because it can't figure out what T is.

It doesn't mean that `First<>()` isn't available, it's just mean that you have to specify what T is.

Consider the following code snippet:

```
        var l2 = new List2();

        l2.First<Class1>();
        l2.First<Class2>();
```

Both `First<Class1>()` and `First<Class2>()` are available and since then the compiler cannot figure out what is `T`.

But in this code snippet:

```
l2.First((Class2 c) => c.ToString() == "");
```

The compiler can figure that `T` is `Class2` so the following will compile just fine.

## Good design practice

Even though the previous approach is valid, it isn't a good design practice to have a class that inherits the same interface twice. (in you case, once via `Class1`, and second via the explicit inherits of `IEnumerable<Class2>`). For a better design you may implement a common abstract class and make your lists to derive form this class.

```
public abstract class CommonListBase
{

}

public class List1 : CommonListBase, IEnumerable<Class1>
{
    public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<Class1> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return new Class1();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}


public class List2 : CommonListBase, IEnumerable<Class2>
{
    public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<Class2> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return new Class2();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```